# Does inheritance include extending and implementing? Conceptual understanding

Tags: c#, oop

I'm just trying to understand this a bit. Does Inheritance mean you've extended a class (or abstract class) but can also mean you've just implemented an interface? Other questions are about their actual usage and I'm looking for a conceptually understanding

Comment: If you are strict, inheritance does not include implementing an interface. Because a class implements (as you already noted yourself) an interface, it does not inherit from it. Now, humans sometimes are not very strict in their uses of words, and sometimes they use words in a fuzzy, ambiguous and sometimes even somewhat incorrect manner. (Fun fact: Interfaces can extend interfaces, so there is that to consider, too)

Comment: You inherit from base classes and implement interfaces.  You can inherit from a base class without also extending it, though that's rather pointless to do so.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, there is a proposal for the next C# version (C# 8) about the support for default interface methods, which -- if that proposal would make it into C# 8 -- makes the distinction between interfaces and abstract classes a little less clear-cut (for a lack of a better term).

Comment: @elgonzo: They got that idea from Java; it's a terrible idea unless perhaps their intention is to bring back multiple inheritance in some form.

Comment: In any case, *extension* is the more general term for what happens when you *implement* an interface or *inherit* from a base class.  It can also refer to something you put in your browser.  Java uses the `extends` keyword to indicate inheritance.

Comment: This isn't really a StackOverflow question, but... C# uses "inherit" to mean inheriting from a base class (what Java calls "extending" (I believe) and what is known as "specialization" in other contexts).  However C# also uses "inherit" to mean "implementing an interface".  Many folks (myself included) never use the word in that context (similarly, I refer to what C# calls a "destructor" as a "finalizer").  Some folks say tom-AY-to, others say to-mah-to.

Comment: Because the OP is a beginner, I believe we should endeavor to keep things simple and straightforward until they have the basics down.  It's okay to give incomplete, simplified, or slightly misleading answers until the concepts are understood.  See ["Lies to Children"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie-to-children).

Answer (score 0):

When you inherit, you now have relationships between the parent and derived class. Therefore, you have access to what the parent class offers. Example, the parent class has a function to add two numbers, well now the child class can use that function without having to implement its functionality. When you extend a class, you're taking that parent class and your adding to it. So in the derived class you added a new function that now allows you to subtract. Because of this inheriting and extending are interchangeable. When inheriting or extending a class you're not obligated to implement an interface because it's assumed that if you're working off an interface, the interface should of been implemented when you constructed the parent class. When you implement an interface it implies that the entire interface must be defined by whatever class implements it, whereas inheriting/extending implies parts of classed are being consumed.

Comment: Ahh okay. Makes sense. Thanks for the breakdown. It seems like there should be another word to encompass all of these as a "pillar of oop." Like Inheritance is a thing, but also extending a class is a thing. 
So with abstraction.. you extend an abstract class... but you could also JUST inherit it?

Comment: @KathrineStack To use an analogy, say your distant relative dies and you inherit their estate.  Once its yours, you have complete access to the entire estate, and you can therefore do whatever you want with it, but this doesn't mean you have to *do* anything with it.  Once its yours, you can just sit on it.  Inheritance doesn't necessitate extension, but it does make it possible.